# How to take an integer array and convert it into other types?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I'm currently trying to take integer arrays that actually represent other data types and convert them into the correct datatype.

So for example, if I had the integer array [1196773188, 542327116], I discover that this integer array represents a string from some other function, convert it, and realize it represents the string "DOUGLAS". The first number translates to the hexadecimal number 0x47554F44 and the second number represents the hexadecimal number 0x2053414C. Using a hex to string converter, these correspond to the strings 'GOUD' and 'SAL' respectively, spelling DOUGLAS in a little endian manner. The way the letters are backwards in individual elements of the array likely stem from the bytes being stored in a litte endian manner, although I might be mistaken on that.

These integer arrays could represent a number of datatypes, including strings, booleans, and floats.

I need to use Python 2.7, so I unfortunately can't use the bytes function.

Is there a simple way to convert an integer array to its corresponding datatype?

Comment: In what way is that list of integers supposed to represent "DOUGLAS"? There isn't a natural default correspondence between strings and lists of integers. Most likely, performing this conversion will require some information you haven't told us, and which you might not have bothered to preserve (in which case this is a lost cause).

Comment: 1st it looks like you have a list: `type([1196773188, 542327116])` -> `<class 'list'>` second the way to convert one piece of data to another is to have some rules/process to convert it.  If you know the rules for how `[1196773188, 542327116]` translates to `"DOUGLAS"` I'd assume that same process of conversion would work with other data. Although I don't really see the correlation.

Comment: Edited to explain why the integers translate to "DOUGLAS"

Comment: Take a look at the [struct](https://pymotw.com/2/struct/) module, which provides tools for converting between binary data and other data types.

Comment: Do you want to know how to do the conversion or how to determine the corresponding datatype?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the struct module is the best way to go when converting between different types like this:

```
import struct    

bufferstr = ""
dougarray = [1196773188, 542327116]
for num in dougarray:
    bufferstr += struct.pack("i", num)

print bufferstr # Result is 'DOUGLAS'
```

From this point on we can easily convert 'DOUGLAS' to any datatype we want using struct.unpack():

```
print struct.unpack("f", bufferstr[0:4]) # Result is (54607.265625)
```

We can only unpack a certain number of bytes at a time however. Thank you all for the suggestions!